# Displaying friends using a pp without a accesstoken

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have looked at the FB api but i can not see where you can display the friends using a app without authorizing first. So when some visits my app without logging in/authorizing the app it displays at the bottom of the app. I have seen a few app that does this but the only one i have found is you need to have a access token for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a user's data (or find out who they are) without them authorising your app and allowing access - basically your users must log in for you to see their friends list, etc. 
This is intentional.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case but where other apps use it i thought it must be able to be done. Thanks

Comment: You can use the [Facepile Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) which will show a logged-in-to-facebook-but-not-longged-in-to-your-app user which of their friends are connected to an object (e.g your app) but you won't be able to see which friends are displayed there

Comment: Arh, i already looked at this but i  have just read through it again and saw the bit i needed and its working. Thanks